# How to check if an element tag is end element

Tags: c#, xml

For example, I have the following type of condition:

```
if (reader.IsStartElement("element1"))
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (reader.IsStartElement("element2"))
        {
            // Doing stuff
            reader.ReadEndElement(); //closes element2 tag
        }
        else if (reader.IsStartElement("element3"))
        {
           // Doing stuff
           reader.ReadEndElement(); //closes element3 tag
        }
        else if ((!reader.IsStartElement("element2")) 
                && (!reader.IsStartElement("element3")) 
                && (!reader.IsEndElement("element1"))) // THIS IS MY ISSUE
        {
           throw new XmlException("exception");
        }
        else
        {
           reader.ReadEndElement(); //closes element1 tag
        }    
    }
}
```

My xml is written in the following type of format:

```
<element1>
    <element2>
    </element2>
    <element3>
    </element3>
</element1>
```

What I want to do is say if there is an element being read inside of `element1` that is not `element2` or `element3` and is not the ending element tag for `element1` then throw the exception that I have written.  The problem is that there is no method for checking an end element tag for XmlReader that I can find.  I can check `reader.IsStartElement` but not `reader.IsEndElement`.  Is there another way I can check if the type is end element?

Comment: There are better ways to read xml with xmlreader.  See my code at following posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34274568/how-to-read-an-xml-file-by-using-xmlreader-in-c-sharp

Comment: I think that link might be broken?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check for the NodeType, and then verify it's the end tag for element1 using reader.Name

```
if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement)
{
    if(reader.Name == "element1")
    {
        //it's element1 end tag
    }
    else
    {
       //it's the end tag for something else
    }
}
```

Comment: Makes sense.  Is there in this instance that doing else if ((!reader.IsStartElement("element2")) 
                && (!reader.IsStartElement("element3")) 
                && (!reader.Name != "element1")) would not work or be a bad idea?  Because in this case I guess I do not need to verify that it is not an end element if I can just verify that the reader is not the name of the ending element if that makes sense

Comment: Cool. Just curious.  Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 2):

You should use `reader.Read()` to move through the XML, and look at the reader's [NodeType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.nodetype(v=vs.110).aspx).

The `XmlNodeType` enumeration contains values for both `Element` and `EndElement`.

Comment: Would I need to use reader.Read()after each condition to be able to move past that element and on to the next?

Comment: Also when I try this it throws an error saying that I cannot use the ! operator with XmlNodeType.  I need to determine that the element tag I'm looking at is NOT the ending tag for element1...

Comment: You should most likely be using `.Read()` in your `while()` condition instead of having an infinite loop. See the example in the page I linked to. And to compare a value against an enumeration, you can use `!=`: `reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement`.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the documentation and advice.